# Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, wmi-service

I'm trying to rename around 100 computer remotely. I have a csv file that is being importer and using rename-computer command to change the computer name but i'm facing the following error.

```
Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'COMPUTERNAME' with the following error message:
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

```
Import-Csv c:/Temp/names.csv | ForEach-Object {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.IPAddress -NewName $_.NewName -LocalCredential localhost\administrator -DomainCredential Domain\Administrator -Force -PassThru -Restart}
```

I went through alot of articles and did try the following stuff:

- checked the services
- turned off windows firewall
- set this key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM\AllowAnonymousCallback`
  to `0`
- set this key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole\AppCompat\RequireIntegrityActivationAuthenticationLevel` to `0`
- checked WMI security, full permissions are there.

Comment: Is there anyone to help here, please?